# Containing one Web Application inside a Script

Tags: php

I want to modify the response and requests to any web application, ( ex Moodle ) for that I would like to have a simple proxy script which will call the main script. Now this script can modify requests and response, What I really want to know is how to handle redirects,

Lets say this is my existing code for that script, this really fails when the original scripts redirects to something. Also I dont know how to handle somethig like this

application/something/something/something  ( as in the case with wordpress )

```
<?php



ob_start();


include('index.php');


$content = ob_get_contents();


echo $content."<!-- at the end -->";


?>
```

Comment: Since you've not streamed anything to the user as it's been captured in your output buffer, you can modify the headers. check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php if you want to "cancel" a location header. Is this what you're kind of wanting to achieve?

Comment: Well, that is not a solution, what i really want is that even after redirect it should go from my script so that I can change request and response.

Comment: You could use [headers_list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) to get a list of the headers that will be sent and modify the redirect headers by deleting/replacing them.